# How to manually fit AR(1) model?

Tags: time-series, estimation, linear, autoregressive

I am trying to fit an AR(1) model using linear model fitting (`lm` in R). Why am I not getting the correct coefficient? (Ground truth from sim is `0.71234`, but I am getting `-0.49979`.)

```
> set.seed(0)
> ts.sim <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = c(0.71234)), n = 1e4)
> arima(ts.sim,order = c(1,0,0))

Call:
arima(x = ts.sim, order = c(1, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
      0.7168     0.0346
s.e.  0.0070     0.0352

sigma^2 estimated as 0.9925:  log likelihood = -14152.01,  aic = 28310.01

# -----------------------------------------------------
# try to manually fit with lm
# -----------------------------------------------------


> x= diff(ts.sim)
> y=ts.sim[-1e4]
> lm(y~x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    0.03542     -0.49979
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model you are currently estimating is not AR(1). There are two problems with it:

1. `y=ts.sim[-100]` should be replaced by `y=ts.sim[-1]`. (Why `100`?)
2. `x=diff(ts.sim)` should be replaced by `x=ts.sim[-1e4]`. (Why difference the variable?)

```r
    > set.seed(0)
    > ts.sim <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = c(0.71234)), n = 1e4)
    > arima(ts.sim,order = c(1,0,0))
    
    Call: arima(x = ts.sim, order = c(1, 0, 0))
    
    Coefficients:
             ar1  intercept
          0.7168     0.0346 s.e.  0.0070     0.0352
    
    sigma^2 estimated as 0.9925:  log likelihood = -14152.01,  aic =
    28310.01
    > x=ts.sim[-1e4]
    > y=ts.sim[-1]
    > lm(y~x)
    
    Call: lm(formula = y ~ x)
    
    Coefficients: (Intercept)            x  
       0.009936     0.716770
```

The AR coefficients estimated by the two methods match up up to a rounding error.

Comment: thanks for the answer. For some reason, i got very confused when I was reading ARIMA, where when talking about the relationship between current and lag, I was thinking about diff....

Comment: should be -1e4 not -100, i was running simulation on different n and forgot to make it consisent.

Comment: @HaitaoDu, sure, I though so. I am glad we got things cleared up :)

Comment: BTW, I found if use my formula, the coefficient will converge to $0.5$ when $N$ get large. Why?

Comment: @HaitaoDu, is it regardless of the true coefficient?

Comment: @HaitaoDu, interesting... Go ahead and open one.

Comment: Thanks for helping me on this question, could you help me with [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505873/how-to-manually-fit-ma1-model-with-lm) also? it seems unclear for me to write $w_t$ and $w_{t-1}$