# How to manually fit MA1 model with OLS?

Tags: time-series, estimation, least-squares, linear, moving-average

We can manually fit AR1 model using linear model, as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505836/how-to-manually-fit-ar1-model).

But how to manually fit MA1 model? following code seems incorrect .., but how can we write the explanatory variable $w_t$ and $w_{t-1}$ ?

```
set.seed(0)
ts.sim <- arima.sim(list(order = c(0,0,1), ma = c(0.3)), n = 1e4)
y=ts.sim
lm(y~1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can estimate an MA model using OLS, but you need to do it iteratively.

Consider an MA(1) without intercept:

$$
y_t = \epsilon_t + \theta\epsilon_{t-1}.
$$

The algorithm is:

Set an initial value, $\theta^{(0)}=0$. Fix $\hat{\epsilon}_0=0$. For $j=1, \dots, n_{iter}$ do:

1. Compute the current estimate of the error terms,
   $$
   \hat{\epsilon}_t^{(j-1)}=y_t-\hat{\theta}^{(j-1)}\hat{\epsilon}_{t-1}^{(j-1)}
   $$
2. Run a regression of $y_t$ on $\hat{\epsilon}_{t-1}^{(j-1)}$ and update $\hat{\theta}^{(j)}$
3. Repeat

Here is some R code and a figure showing how the estimate evolves in 10 iterations:

```
set.seed(1)   

N <- 1000
nIter <- 10

eps <- rnorm(N+1)
theta <- 0.5
y <- eps[2:(N+1)] + theta * eps[1:N]

epsEst <- numeric(N+1)
epsEst[1] <- 0
thetaEst <- 0
thetaEstStorage <- numeric(nIter)
thetaEstStorage[1] <- thetaEst
for (j in 2:nIter) {
  for (i in 1:N) {
    epsEst[i+1] <- y[i] - thetaEst * epsEst[i]
  }
  mod <- lm(y ~ 0 + epsEst[1:N])
  thetaEst <- coef(mod)
  thetaEstStorage[j] <- thetaEst
}

ts.plot(thetaEstStorage, ylim = c(-1, 1))
abline(h = theta, col = "red")
```

[image: enter image description]

Comment: +1. I would not call this OLS, though; IRWLS would be more appropriate. I think the conceptual difference is substantial, especially since we are dealing with *unobservable* series as regressors here.

Comment: @RichardHardy Sure, I see your point and it's definitely not standard OLS estimation. My goal was just to illustrate that if the OP was asking how to estimate an MA model using *only* OLS, then that is certaintly possible.

Comment: Yes, and you did that well.

Comment: What does IRWLS stand for?

Answer (score 2):

Consider an MA(q) model
$$
y_t=c+\varepsilon_t+\theta_1\varepsilon_{t-1}+\dots+\theta_q\varepsilon_{t-q}.
$$
You cannot fit the model with OLS (which the `lm` function is doing). Since the regressors $\varepsilon_{t-i}$ for $i=1,\dots,q$ are unobserved, you cannot construct the $X$ matrix* neeeded for the OLS solution $\beta=(c,\theta_1,\dots,\theta_q)=(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top y$. The model can be estimated using maximum likelihood via Kalman filtering.

*In this model, for the OLS estimator to work the regressor matrix would need to be $X=(\mathbf{1},\varepsilon_{t-1},\dots,\varepsilon_{t-q})$.

Comment: This has been discussed in multiple posts before, so if you find a duplicate, you may mark the question accordingly.